# Extracting Data from XML with Python

Tags: python, xml

I have this code and I need extract the comment counts from the XML data, compute ( http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_228073.xml) the sum of the numbers in the file and enter the sum.
 I like to know what part of code I need to introduce because I had already used different codes to extract the sum of the numbers

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

serviceurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?'

while True:
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
    print data
    tree = ET.fromstring(data)

    results = tree.findall('result')
    lat = results[0].find('geometry').find('location').find('lat').text
    lng = results[0].find('geometry').find('location').find('lng').text
    location = results[0].find('formatted_address').text

    print 'lat',lat,'lng',lng
    print location
```

Comment: How can I resolve this code to obtain the sum of the statement?